# Trying to check if object exists in Knockout Observable Array

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout.js

I'm trying to check if an object has the same observable values of other objects with the same observable properties inside an observable array.

I created a foreach loop which evaluates if any of the observables match. The problem I'm having is that condition always evaluates to true, even though these values are different.   I'm using typescript and knockout.

Here's the code :

```
 export function addPDFToPackage(heat: MTRHeat): void {

    var koHeat: MTRHeatWithInclude = ko.mapping.fromJS(heat);
    koHeat.Include = ko.observable(true);

    var arrayOfHeats = model.mtrPackage.Heats();
    var addToHeats = () => model.mtrPackage.Heats.push(koHeat);

    var duplicate = false;

    arrayOfHeats.forEach(function (koHeat, i) {
        if (arrayOfHeats[i].MTRID() == koHeat.MTRID() && arrayOfHeats[i].HeatID() == koHeat.HeatID() && arrayOfHeats[i].PartID() == koHeat.PartID()) {
            duplicate = true;
        }
        else
            duplicate = false;
    })

    if (!!model.mtrPackage.PackageID()) {
        if (duplicate) {
            var c = confirm("Warning: Duplicate MTR located on current package.Proceed ?")
            if (c) {
                ServiceMethods.addHeatToPackage(model.mtrPackage.PackageID(), heat.HeatID).done(addToHeats);
            }
            if (!c) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have pushed koHeat at the end of the array and I think that's what returning true (not all the elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Your loop compares each object to itself because you re-use the variable name `koHeat`. I believe you really wanted to refer to the "outer" `koHeat`.

Second problem: You overwrite the `duplicate` variable in every loop iteration. This is probably not what you intend. Instead you want to stop the loop as soon as a duplicate is found.

How about something along those lines?

```
export function addPDFToPackage(heat: MTRHeat): void {
    var koHeat: MTRHeatWithInclude = ko.mapping.fromJS(heat);
    var packageId = model.mtrPackage.PackageID();

    koHeat.Include = ko.observable(true);

    function equals(a: MTRHeatWithInclude, b: MTRHeatWithInclude): boolean {
        return a.MTRID() == b.MTRID() && a.HeatID() == b.HeatID() && a.PartID() == b.PartID();
    }

    if ( !!packageId && (
        !model.mtrPackage.Heats().some(item => equals(item, koHeat)) ||
        confirm("Warning: Duplicate MTR located on current package.Proceed ?")
        )
    ) {
        ServiceMethods.addHeatToPackage(packageId, heat.HeatID).done(() => {
            model.mtrPackage.Heats.push(koHeat);
        });
    }
}
```

The `equals()` function should ideally be a method of the `MTRHeatWithInclude` class.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're getting a clash between `koHeat` defined here:

```
var koHeat: MTRHeatWithInclude = ko.mapping.fromJS(heat);
koHeat.Include = ko.observable(true);
```

And the variable defined within the `forEach` call.  It's always returning true as (within the scope of the `forEach`) `arrayOfHeats[i] === koHeat`.

Try this:

```
 export function addPDFToPackage(heat: MTRHeat): void {

    var koHeat: MTRHeatWithInclude = ko.mapping.fromJS(heat);
    koHeat.Include = ko.observable(true);

    var arrayOfHeats = model.mtrPackage.Heats();
    var addToHeats = () => model.mtrPackage.Heats.push(koHeat);

    var duplicate = false;

    arrayOfHeats.forEach(function (koHeat2, i) {
        if (koHeat2.MTRID() == koHeat.MTRID() && 
            koHeat2.HeatID() == koHeat.HeatID() && 
            koHeat2.PartID() == koHeat.PartID()) {
            duplicate = true;
        }
    })

    if (!!model.mtrPackage.PackageID()) {
        if (duplicate) {
            var c = confirm("Warning: Duplicate MTR located on current package.Proceed ?")
            if (c) {
                ServiceMethods.addHeatToPackage(model.mtrPackage.PackageID(), heat.HeatID).done(addToHeats);
            } else {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```